# Uploading image to google cloud I got error A keyfile was given

Tags: laravel, google-cloud-storage, service-accounts, google-iam

Under https://console.cloud.google.com/ I created new app and created json file with credentials
and in .env I added line :

```
GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE="client_secret_NNNNMYFILE.apps.googleusercontent.com.json"
```

but I got error tring to upload my image to google cloud:

```
A keyfile was given, but it does not contain a project ID. This can indicate an old and obsolete keyfile, in which case you should create a new one. To suppress this message, set `suppressKeyFileNotice` to `true` in your client configuration. To learn more about generating new keys, see this URL: https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#creating_service_account_keys
```

What kind of project ID is it ? Is it some option under console.cloud.google ? Where can I set it ?
I opened the link above but I did not find any “suppressKeyFileNotice” mentioned there...

**File  Project/public/client_secret_278938643693-44adrhckvqgbcikr943lj29tvg89hojr.apps.googleusercontent.com.json has content :**

```
{"web":{"client_id":"NNNNNNhojr.apps.googleusercontent.com","project_id":"tads-gsc-test","auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth","token_uri":"https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token","auth_provider_x509_cert_url":"https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v1/certs","client_secret":"NNNN-NNNNNNNN","redirect_uris":["https://my-site-ref.com/authorized_redirect"],"javascript_origins":["https:///my-site-ref.com"]}}
```

Control action :

```
$fileContents= Storage::url('public/todo_list_app/1/logo-file.jpeg'); ;

$disk = Storage::disk('gcs');

$disk->put('avatars/1', $fileContents);
$exists = $disk->exists('logo-file.jpeg');

$time = $disk->lastModified('file1.jpg');
```

In config/filesystems.php :

```
'gcs' => [
    'driver' => 'gcs',
    'key_file_path' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE', null), // optional: /path/to/service-account.json
    'key_file' => [], // optional: Array of data that substitutes the .json file (see below)
    'project_id' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_PROJECT_ID', 'your-project-id'), // optional: is included in key file
    'bucket' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_BUCKET', 'your-bucket'),
    'path_prefix' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_PATH_PREFIX', ''), // optional: /default/path/to/apply/in/bucket
    'apiEndpoint' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_STORAGE_API_URI', null), // see: Public URLs below
    'visibility' => 'public', // optional: public|private
    'metadata' => ['cacheControl'=> 'public,max-age=86400'], // optional: default metadata
],
```

How can I fix it?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Show the first couple of lines from the JSON file. I think you are using the wrong type of credentials file. Also, show your code. https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: I added more info

Comment: You are trying to use OAuth Client Secret credentials instead of a service account JSON key file. https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#get-key

Comment: Thanks for provided link. 
I try to follow it , but I did not find relative pages of points :
>>> 1) Click the email address of the service account whose keys you want to list.
>>> 2) Click Keys. The Google Cloud console displays a list of keys for the service account, including metadata for each key.

That is project page https://prnt.sc/KZDfUP-SBMPH  and Credentials : https://prnt.sc/d7CvjxR8i-tC
?

Comment: I am not sure what you are trying to say, but I think you are at the wrong place for service accounts. https://console.cloud.google.com/projectselector/iam-admin/serviceaccounts/

Comment: @PetroGromovo,Please let me know if my answer was helpful or you need any further information.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general process to build an application using Google Cloud APIs, follow these general steps:

- Choose and use the provided Google Cloud Client Libraries
- Determine the correct authentication flow for your application
- Find or create the application credentials needed for your
  application
- Pass the application credentials to the client libraries at
  application startup time, ideally through Application Default
  Credentials [4] (ADC)

You should choose application credentials based on what your application needs and where it runs.

To use service accounts with the Google Cloud CLI, you need to set an environment variable [5]where your code runs.

Provide authentication credentials to your application code by setting the environment variable `GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS`. This variable applies only to your current shell session. If you want the variable to apply to future shell sessions, set the variable in your shell startup file, for example in the `~/.bashrc` or `~/.profile file`.

Also, as per comments and suggestions ,you are using the OAuth 2.0 Client IDs secret json file,whereas you should instead be using the right service account keys json file[1].

`key_file_path' => env('GOOGLE_CLOUD_KEY_FILE', null), // optional: /path/to/service-account.json`

You may refer to the following for more information
[1]:https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys#get-key
[2] : https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/getting-started
[3] :https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/best-practices-applications
[4] : https://cloud.google.com/docs/authentication/production#automatically
[5] : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable